# Can't connect shapes via Shape.Name =

Tags: vba, excel

I want to connect different shapes in Excel with connectors using the following code:

`Set Shape = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, X, Y, w, h)
With Shape
.Name = ExampleName+i
End With`

For some reason, I can only add connectors via `Shape` but not via `ExampleName+i`.

`conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect Shape, 1` <- Works
`conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect ExampleName+i, 1 <- Does not work

Any suggestion how to solve this? I need this because the shapes are created within a For Loop and are meant to have different names.

Comment: `w.Shapes("ExampleName")....`

Comment: It looks like tigeravatar has already given you the solution.  To apply it to your example, use `w.Shapes(ExampleName & i)`.

Comment: Yes, that did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While you are in the For Loop, you can refer to the create shape as whatever you set it to as long as you only work with one shape at a time. In this case Shape (I would change this variable).

So the loop would look something like:

```
Sub test()
For each strName in strNames()
    Set shpRectangle = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, X, Y, w, h)
    With shpRectangle
        .Name = strName
    End With
    shpRectangle.       <rest of code>
Next strName
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is I can only connect the shapes via `shpTectangle` and not via `strName`. Somehow there is no reaction if I use strName; Can I have the `shpTectangle` as a dynamic variable instead?

Comment: @ThatOneGuy, please do not use `With ... End With` to simplify one line. `shpRectangle.Name = strName` is much easier to read than the three lines that you used